# If P = NP, why does P = NP = NP-Complete?

Tags: complexity-theory, computation-theory

If `P = NP`, why does `P = NP` also then equal `NP-Complete`?

I.e. Why would it then be the case that `P = NP = NP-Complete`?

Assuming `P != NP` , there were problems in NP not in NP - Complete.
When `P = NP`, all NP problems are actually now P.

Shouldn't there still be `P = NP` problems not in `NP - Complete`?

[image]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about CS theory and would be better suited to http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

for future reference, no code = does not belong in stackoverflow...

as for your answer, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-complete provides a full explanation. In 'layman' terms, all NP problems can be converted to an NP-C problem with a polynomial converter. that means that if P=NP, all of NP can be converted to NP-C which by definition can be converted to another NP-C etc. so P=NP=NP-C.